# Display text only if text is more than x lines

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I wish to output some text to a table cell. If this text is more than x lines I trim it and add a "see more" button.

Up to here everything is great, the problem is that the "see more" button is there also when I have a `y<x` lines of text.

Is there a way to check whether the text is more\less than x lines?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: show us your existing code first

Comment: if http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php < X { } else {}

Comment: add the see more button dynamically when you trim that text and add that in html tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have the line number based on the height of the element, if one line have 10px height 10 lines have 100px height
Vanilla js:

```
let height = document.getElementById('IdElement').offsetHeight;
```

Jquery library:

```
let height = $('#IdElement').height();
```

with this variable you can do the logic to find out the amount of lines

to directly have the line number you need to put each line in a tag be it `p`, `span`, whatever
Perhaps the easiest is actually to take this with the height of the element

Comment: Thanks for the answer - very helpful. For some reason the onload event doesnt work for <td> tags, i'll try and dig into that.

Your help is much appreciated